# Stop uploading to internet in ubuntu

Tags: privileges, upload

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

I want to disable uploading files to internet (dropbox or email or any website) from my machine

Is there any way to applied this in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Yes, just disconnect from the internet, and no uploading whatsoever will take place.

Comment: I want to keep browsing

Comment: Do you want to set things up so that applications that access the Internet cannot access most of your files? Or do you want to prevent *any data* from being uploaded? Or something else? It's possible to prevent any data from being uploaded with `iptables`, but *you would also not be able to initiate any downloads*--you would not even be able to load a web page--since that requires *uploading* requests to a server. I recommend *editing your question* to provide more details about your needs. Also, you should decide whether you want this question here on Ask Ubuntu, or on Super User.

Comment: I want to keep browsing but disable upload file
the final Goal I want to give my computer to someone to read my files but I fear if he get a copy of my file with keeping browsing if he want search about something

Comment: Why don't you want that person to be able to upload your files? In theory, if this person can read the files, she can just copy them and do whatever she wants with the copy.

Comment: USB is disable 

and he can't make like my files because the files is very complicated and if he get copy of them he can make money

Comment: I wouldn't put in risk such information. It will be preferably to run a private presentation in which YOU are in control of the situation by showing him/them exactly what you wish them to "see" (note "see"). There are a lot of ways to extract the information from a computer and it's not limited to USB/CD/DVD. I can -IE- remove the hard disk drive and place it in a different computer so I will get the files with ease and in a snap.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to keep browsing

is incompatible with

> disable uploading files to internet

Here is why:

- Any website you browse involves two-way traffic: your computer sends data to the website, and the website sends data back to your computer.
- A user who is "just browsing" a website could type in anything they want. they could, if they wanted, run `base64` to encode any arbitrary file (image, video, etc.) into ASCII text, and paste that on any website that isn't blocked.
- You can install a web filter that attempts to block out many sites where it is possible to upload stuff, but for every site that your filter blocks, I can create a new website or virtual machine somewhere that lets me upload files, and upload any file by copy and paste, base64, or any other method.
- You can install a whitelist that only lets you access a pre-defined list of websites, but this has several problems. Firstly, there are many sites that you might not think of when you create the whitelist that you DO want to browse to, and you'll have to add them to the whitelist manually as you discover these sites. Secondly, even if you whitelist a certain site, that site may have some feature or section you are not aware of, which lets you upload stuff still. They might even introduce this as a "new" feature *after* you add it to the whitelist.

It is not possible in the general case to absolutely prevent any file on your system from being uploaded to the internet, without disconnecting entirely from the internet.

Comment: the final Goal I want to give my computer to someone to read my files but I fear if he get a copy of my file with keeping browsing if he want search about something